# std::chrono is not working properly in std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, timer, c++-chrono

I wrote a class, that does some action every second. Here it is:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
class TimerTest
{
public:
    TimerTest()
    {
        m_start = steady_clock::now();
    }
    void update() // is called every iteration of the main loop
    {
        if (duration_cast<seconds>(steady_clock::now() - m_start) >= m_duration)
        {
            m_start = steady_clock::now();
            std::cout << 1; // some action
        }
    }
private:
    time_point<steady_clock> m_start;

    duration<double> m_duration = seconds(1);
};
```

It works fine when it's defined by a separate variable:

```
int main()
{
    TimerTest timer_test;
    while (true)
    {
        timer_test.update();
    }
}
```

Every second '1' is printed to the console.
But the problem appears, when I put my class into a vector:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<TimerTest> vec;
    vec.push_back(TimerTest());
    
    while (true)
    {
        for (auto i : vec)
        {
            i.update();
        }
    }
}
```

In a vector this `if (duration_cast<seconds>(steady_clock::now() - m_start) >= duration)` line works wrong, and the time, elapsed since the last `m_start` update is always bigger than `m_duration`. So, '1' is printed to the console every iteration of the loop.
I'm really curious to know about the reason of such strange behaviour and how to fix it. Maybe I don't know something about vectors, because i'm not very experienced in c++.
So, please, help me to understand it.

Comment: `for (auto i : vec)` Here `i` is a  *copy* of the vector element. You want `for (auto &i : vec)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that your range based for loop is making a copy of the `TimerTest` and updating the copy rather than the original.  Try...

```
for (auto &i: vec) {
    i.update();
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I didn't even think that the mistake was in this place.